# Как добавить звук при выводе изображения

Tags: javascript

Работаю над скриптом, который перехватывает нажатие кнопок клавиатуры и вместо их значений выводит на экран нужные изображения. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы вывод каждого изображения сопровождался проигрыванием определенного соответствующего ему звукового файла? Т.е. я нажимаю, к примеру, на "Q", вижу на экране картинку и одновременно на фоне слышу звук, потом нажимаю W, вижу другую картинку и другой звук? Доп. библиотеки не хотелось бы использовать, если это возможно, только чистый JS.

P.S. Это нужно для научной работы, а не для террора пользователей какого-нибудь сайта разными звуками:) Несколько часов провела в гугле, но т.к. плохо разбираюсь в этой теме, не смогла адаптировать имеющиеся примеры под свой случай. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
function keyEvent(){
var imgSrc = null;
var container = document.getElementById( 'storage' );

switch(event.keyCode){
    case 81: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/2.jpg"; break; } // "Q"
    case 87: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/3.jpg"; break; } // "W"
    case 69: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/4.jpg"; break; } // "E"
    case 82: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/5.jpg"; break; } // "R"
    case 84: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/6.jpg"; break; } // "T"
    case 89: { imgSrc="http://posudoria.ru/parlament/7.jpg"; break; } // "Y"
    case 13: {
    if (container.lastElementChild.childElementCount) {
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    line.className = 'line';
    container.appendChild( line );
  }
    break;
}
    case 8: { 
  event.preventDefault();
  if(container.childElementCount) {
    if (!container.lastElementChild.childElementCount) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastElementChild);
    }
container.lastElementChild.removeChild(container.lastElementChild.lastElementChild);
  }
}
  }

  if( imgSrc == null ) return;

  var img = document.createElement('img'),
    div = document.createElement('div');

  img.setAttribute("src", imgSrc);
  div.className = 'container';
  div.appendChild( img );
  if (!container.childElementCount) {
var line = document.createElement("div");
line.className = 'line';
container.appendChild(line);
  }
  container.lastElementChild.appendChild( div );
}
document.body.onkeydown = keyEvent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проиграть звук на странице можно с помощью тега [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) в DOM или объекта [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) в javascript (по сути это одно и тоже). Если смотреть немного шире, то можно воспользоваться всей мощью [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). Но для ваших целей будет достаточно объекта Audio и его метода [play](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp).

Для этого нужны данные, которые HTMLAudioElement может интерпретировать как звук. В вашем случае вам будет достаточно найти подходящие звуковые файлы, разместить их у себя на сервере, и ссылаться на них про создании аудио-объекта.

Для этого достаточно в js-коде написать конструкцию:

```
var audio = new Audio('<url>');
audio.play();
```

При этом файл будет загружен, и сразу после этого проигран. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/j3wu2qo5/).

Чтобы проигрывать звук по нажатию на клавишу, нужно поместить эту конструкцию в обработчик нажатия клавиш.

Надо заметить, что если просто поместить такую конструкцию в обработчик, то мы столкнемся с двумя важными последствиями:

1. При первом нажатии клавиши с опр. звуком, этот звук проиграется с некоторой задержкой после нажатия, т.к. файл нужно будет откуда-то загрузить.
2. Каждый раз, при нажатии клавиши будет создаваться Audio объект, что может привести к большому расходованию памяти и лагам.

Для оптимизации, стоит подгружать ресурсы до того, как пользователь сможет ими воспользоваться. Например, перед запуском игры вы можете создать список объектов Audio, поставив их в очередь на загрузку. Чтобы проверить статус загрузки, нужно подписаться на событие [canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough). [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2zu792sw/).

Другим способом может быть помещение всего набора аудио-файлов в виде тегов audio в DOM страницы изначально. В таком случае, для их кеширования нужно найти их с помощью одного из [способов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), установить обработчик события canplaythrough и вызвать на них метод `load`.

Это также относится и к картинкам. Стоит их все подгружать заранее, если это возможно.

Бесплатные наборы звуков можно найти на https://www.freesound.org.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все получилось.